# Heap allocation vs. stack allocation while initializing a struct object

Tags: c++, struct

I'm testing a simple algorithm to remove linked list elements. I have the following code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeElements(ListNode* head, int val) {
        ListNode* dummy_head = new ListNode(0);
        dummy_head->next = head;
        ListNode* current = dummy_head;

        while (current->next != NULL) {
            if (current->next->val == val) {
                ListNode* tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                delete tmp;
            } else {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }

        head = dummy_head->next;
        delete dummy_head;
        return head;
    }
};
```

Which runs fine. However, if I change the `ListNode* dummy_head = new ListNode(0);` to `ListNode* dummy_head(0);`, this gives me run time error:

> runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'
> (solution.cpp) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior
> prog_joined.cpp:25:21

I'm not sure what is the difference between these, as it seems like the difference only lies in stack allocation and heap allocation.

I also tried other ways of initialization, like the standard way to init a pointer:

```
ListNode dummy_head_object(0);
ListNode* dummy_head = &dummy_head_object;
```

However I'm seeing:

> ==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: in thread T0 #3 0x7f2d42339082
> (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) Address 0x7ffd4fb4e400 is
> located in stack of thread T0 at offset 32 in frame This frame has 1
> object(s): [32, 48) 'dummy_head_object' <== Memory access at offset 32
> is inside this variable

Could someone shed light on it? Appreciated.

Comment: If you write `ListNode* dummy_head(0);` to which `ListNode` object do you expect `dummy_head` to point? You dereference it immediately in `dummy_head->next = head;`. "_as it seems like the difference only lies in stack allocation and heap allocation_": It has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Would the difference be clearer if you instead of `ListNode* dummy_head(0);`, you used the equivalent `ListNode* dummy_head(nullptr);` or perhaps `ListNode* dummy_head = nullptr;`? (Sometimes it helps to use numbers other than `0` when experimenting.)

Comment: If the way of initialization of a pointer is the issue, with the following code it should work:
        ListNode dummy_head_object(0);
        ListNode* dummy_head = &dummy_head_object;

However I'm seeing 
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: in thread T0
    #3 0x7f2d42339082  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
Address 0x7ffd4fb4e400 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 32 in frame
  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 48) 'dummy_head_object' <== Memory access at offset 32 is inside this variable

Comment: If you don't allocate with `new`, then don't `delete` it ...

Comment: @Skylar *"If the way of initialization of a pointer is the issue"* -- Not exactly. The issue is probably that you are initializing a pointer, not how you are initializing it. It takes a lot of guesswork because your question does not clearly describe your intended functionality. However, for what I'd guess you intended to accomplish, you should be initializing an object (`ListNode dummy_head(0);`), not a pointer. Which incidentally would make your function simpler, dropping 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: Try debugging your application with `gdb` ...